# poll() function trying to detect stdout from jq

Tags: c, pipe, jq, stdout, stdin

I am trying to write a function in C that checks the presence of stdin using `poll()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>

\\other code

void check_stdin(){
    struct pollfd fds;
    int ret; fds.fd = 0; fds.events = POLLIN;
    ret = poll(&fds, 1, 10);
    printf("Return value: %d\n", ret);
    if(ret != 1){
        printf("stdin could not be read\n");
    }
}
```

Here `fds.fd=0` refers to file descriptor for STDIN. `fds.events = POLLIN` refers to the event that there is data to read. I am using a timeout of 10 milliseconds. When I run

```
echo "{\"key\": 1}" | jq .key | ./test_stdin
```

where `test_stdin` is the object file for the C program, I get the output

```
Return value: 0
stdin could not be read
```

The value of `ret` should be 1 if there was data found to be read in the STDIN. Is the STDOUT from `jq` not considered as STDIN for `./test_stdin` here?

Comment: Is your program working as expected if you omit the "jq .key" part ?

Comment: Yes, just ```echo "hello" | ./test_stdin``` works fine. Or something like ```cat test_file.txt | ./test_stdin``` is also okay.

Comment: okay. Then the question is not really about C as you don't have a question for a C program...

Comment: What do you get if you just do: `echo "{\"key\": 1}" | jq .key` ?

Comment: I don't know `jq` but I would try: `echo "{\"key\": 1}" | jq .key 2>&1 | ./test_stdin` to redirect stderr to stdout

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.... Is that the output printed in the console from `echo "{\"key\": 1}" | jq .key` ?

Comment: @SupportUkraine I misread your comment. ```echo "{\"key\": 1}" | jq .key``` should just print ```1``` on the terminal

Comment: hmmm... you write "should just print 1" ... hmm... should!? But does it do that?

Comment: Yes it does, and it is not the stderr, it is stdout.

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition in your shell pipeline.

```c
ret = poll(&fds, 1, 10);
```

You're telling `poll()` to wait for 10 milliseconds before timing out. `jq` wasn't producing any output in that short time when you tested it (Didn't for me either). If you use a longer timeout, say 500 milliseconds, you'll likely see

```
Return value: 1
```

as the output instead.

Commands in a pipeline are all run concurrently, and what order they execute in is dependent on your OS's scheduler. So the C program at the end might actually be ending before `jq` even starts to execute. If programs intended for use in a pipeline use blocking reads, they'll never notice, but with that very short timeout, you're seeing the effects.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I thought the timeout was in seconds, I had not read the documentation of poll() correctly. I'll edit my question accordingly.